# grep matching but not printing if line end in dos ^M

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to search in multiple files for a PATTERN, if found display the file, line and PATTERN surrounded by a few extra chars. My problem is that if the line matching the PATTERN ends with ^M (CRLF) grep prints an empty line instead.

Create a file like this, first line "a^M", second line "a", third line empty line, forth line "a" (not followed by a new line).

```
a^M
a

a
```

Without trying to match a few chars after the PATTERN all occurrences are found and displayed:

```
# grep -srnoEiI ".{0,2}a" *
1:a
2:a
4:a
```

If I try to match any chars at the end of the PATTERN, it prints an empty line instead of line one, the one ending in CRLF:

```
# grep -srnoEiI ".{0,2}a.{0,2}" *

2:a
4:a
```

How can I change this to act as expected ?

P.S. I will like to fix this grep, but I will accept other solutions for example in awk.

**EDIT:**

Based on the answers below I choose to strip the \r and force grep to pipe the colors to tr:

```
grep --color=always -srnoEiI ".{0,2}a.{0,2}" * | tr -d '\r'
```

Comment: Is using the `dos2unix` utility an option, to convert the CRLF endings to LF?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, No, I'm searching through +4GB of source code files, I don't want to touch and change them all.

Comment: @anubhava The output should be the same in the first and second grep example above, your " | cat -vte" is producing the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for answering, after reading your question few more times I realized what you are asking and thus posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simpler case that reproduces your problem:

```
# Output 
echo $'a\r' | grep -o "a"
# No output
echo $'a\r' | grep -o "a."
```

This is beacuse the `^M` matches like a regular character, and makes your terminal overwrite its output (this is purely cosmetic).

How you want to fix this depends on what you want to do.

```
# Show the output in hex format to ensure it's correct
$ echo $'a\r' | grep -o "a." | od -t x1 -c
0000000  61  0d  0a
      a  \r  \n

# Show the output in visually less ambiguous format
$ echo $'a\r' | grep -o "a." | cat -v
a^M

# Strip the carriage return
$ echo $'a\r' | grep -o "a." | tr -d '\r'
a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v pattern="a" '$0 ~ pattern && !/\r$/ {print NR ": " $0}' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/a/{/\r$/!{=;p}}' ~/tmp/srcfile | paste -d: - -
```

Both of these do: find the pattern, see if the line does not end in a carriage return, print the line number and the line. For the sed, the line number is on its own line, so we have to join two consecutive lines with a colon.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more ways:

Use the [`dos2unix` utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) to convert the dos-style line endings to unix-style:

```
dos2unix myfile.txt
```

Or [preprocess the file using `tr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Translating.html) to remove the CR characters, then pipe to grep:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < myfile.txt | grep -srnoEiI ".{0,2}a.{0,2}"
1:a
2:a
4:a
$
```

Note `dos2unix` may need to be installed on whatever OS you are using.  More than likely [`tr` will be available on any POSIX-compliant OS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -n '.{0,2}a.{0,2}' inputfile
```

For your sample input:

```
$ printf $'a\r\na\n\na\n' | pcregrep -n '.{0,2}a.{0,2}' 
1:a
2:a
4:a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk with a custom field separator:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]\r]' '/.{0,2}a.{0,2}/{print FILENAME, NR, $1}' OFS=':' file
```

**TESTING:**

Your grep command:

```
grep -srnoEiI ".{0,2}a.{0,2}" file|cat -vte
file:1:a^M$
file:2:a$
file:4:a$
```

Suggested awk commmand:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]\r]' '/.{0,2}a.{0,2}/{print FILENAME, NR, $1}' OFS=':' file|cat -vte
file:1:a$
file:2:a$
file:4:a$
```